# Do we mention the holiday in the three faceted blessing during chol hamoed?

Tags: blessing, chol-hamoed, birkat-meeyn-shalosh

The three faceted blessing (ברכת מעין שלוש) has an addition for various occasions including Succos and Pesach. Are the additions added as well on [Chol Hamoed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chol_HaMoed) or just Yom Tov? The reason for the question is that the text is

> ושמחנו ביום חג הסכות הזה

which could be taken to mean on the exact day of Succos and not chol hamoed. Then it could also be taken to mean the entire week of Succos. The same question could apply to Pesach as well.

Comment: my text doesn't say "on Yom Tov say" -- it just puts in "On Sukkot say". Why would you think that there is a distinction?

Comment: Do you have the same question about yaaleh veyavo in bentching or davening?

Comment: @rosends I added the reason for the question to the posting.

Comment: @DoubleAA we see that yaaleh veyavo is placed in the davening of chol hamoed so we see that it applies. Thus my question is only on Al Hamichya (though I think that the answer is that it applies but I do not know for sure).

Comment: Why would bentching be different from mein shalosh? It's by definition a summary of bentching.

Comment: Have you considered [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Answer (score 3):

In general, it's a debate, whether we should mention the holiday (מעין המאורע) in the three faceted blessing or not. Rambam in [Mishneh Torah Berakhot 3:13](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/927671/jewish/Berachot-Chapter-Three.htm#v13) says yes, and he seems to base his ruling on [Yerushalmi Berakhot 6:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Berakhot.45b.1). However, [Tosafot](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Berakhot.44a.13) on [Berakhot 44a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.44a.13) never heard about this practice in their land, and were perplexed to read it from Rambam. Still, the [Tur Orach Chayim 208](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%97) agrees with Rambam (Beit Yoseif mentions the debate with sources), and it is how it is codified in the [Shulchan Arukh Orach Chayim 208:12](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%99%D7%91).

Regarding your question in particular, whether we should say it on the intermediate days, I have found a [decision](https://din.org.il/2019/10/20/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A9-%D7%91%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%93/) taking it for granted, but it's [not](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/60037) [evident](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/61046). Citing [Yehudah ben Yitzchak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ben_Isaac_Messer_Leon) the [Or Zarua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Moses_of_Vienna) implies that they had a different text of the Rambam, which included the intermediate days as well ([Hilkhot Seuda 181](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8726&st=&pgnum=70)):

> כתב בספרי הרמב"ם זצ"ל שיש להזכיר בה מעין המאורע בשבתות וימים טובים **ובחוה"מ** ובראשי חדשים.‏
>
> The Rambam זצ"ל wrote in his books that one has to mention in it the reference to the holiday on the Shabbat, holidays, the **intermediate days of the festival** and new moons.

The following reasoning is the same as in the Tosafot. Still, another source, the [Kaf haChayim](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9087&st=&pgnum=276) to Orach Chayim 208:12 clearly rules to say it. CYLOR to know your local custom.

Comment: Rabbi Dov Lior (linked on "evident") was indeed asked specifically about the intermediate days, but his answer seems to refer to the debate that you mentioned between Rambam and Tosafot about whether to  say it ever

Comment: If I'm not missing something, it looks as if he changed his mind. In the first one he says not to say it, but in the next one he says that we do say it. The sources would have to be the ones you already have in your answer; the question of Chol Hammoed doesn't even start according to Tosafot who don't add it even on Yom Tov

Comment: Does the first paragraph add to your answer? It's interesting and all, but I don't see the relevance.

Comment: @ba Doesn't he refer in the latter answer only to the holiday and not the intermediate days? The Rambam vs. Tosafot debate only discusses that part. I had a feeling that he might have overlooked the chol hamoed part of the question. (I added a line break in my answer for better readability. Obviously I'm more interested in the background than just saying yes or no.)

Comment: Interestingly, rambam didn't list rosh chodesh but the shulchan aruch does

Comment: The Kaf Hachaim seems to learn this from Birkat Hamaxon and points to the reference their. However, this is not clear. You should make your answer clearer. Additionally, we may connect the Al Hamichya to the Harachaman in Birkat Hamazon which may only refer to Yom Tov and put in the reference to *Sukkat David Hanofeles* for Chol Hamoed. Also the Rambam does not specifically reference Chol Hamoed and may only mean Yom Tov.