Is there ever a time when one would need to repeat מעין שלש in order to mention Shabbat or Yom Tov?
If one does not have bread to eat on Shabbat, but he has Mezonot - not enough to be Kovei’a Seudah - would he need to repeat Al Hamichya if he forgot to mention Shabbat?

Why mention מעין המאורע in מעין שלוש at all? Does the gemara ever tell us to?

See that the obligation isn't so clear cut https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/117755/759

I've heard it could be a concern if you made kiddush bemakom seudah on mezonos or wine, but I don't know the source (if there is one).

No, there is no need to repeat Me’ein Shalosh if one forgot to mention Shabbos or Yom Tov.
Mishnah Berurah 208:58:

מעין המאורע - היינו קודם שאומר כי אתה ה' טוב ומטיב יאמר בשבת ורצה והחליצנו ביום השבת הזה וביום טוב אומר וזכרנו לטובה ביום חג פלוני הזה וכן בר"ח יאמר וזכרנו לטובה ביום ר"ח הזה ובדיעבד אפילו לא הזכיר מעין המאורע יצא:

